# Where can I find the function view when I call $this->load->view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I extend the class `CI_Controller` and use the `$this->load->view`, and tried to open `controller.php`, I can't find the `view` function.

What does the `$this->load->view` mean? `$this` refers to the `CI_Controller` class. How about the `load` and `view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->load->view will load the view. For example $this->load->view(ABC.php) then it will search for ABC.php in view folder of codeigniter and load it. This line usually be the last line of your controller.

About CI_Controller is the parent controller class so that it can inherit all its functions.

So, if your url is example/abc/demo/ ,CodeIgniter would attempt to find a controller named demo.php and load its view which will be at the last line.

hope this will help.

Comment: in my case, i have `http://localhost:1234/CodeIgniter/index.php/pages/view`
you said that in `example/abc/demo/` CI would find a controller demp.php. But where to find that demo.php? Is it in views? or in controllers folder?

Comment: It will be in controller folder of the project and at the last line you will use $this->load->view to load your view.

Answer (score 1):

`load` is a paroperty with an instance of [`CI_Loader`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/class-CI_Loader.html). `CI_Loader::view` is a method to load a view:

```
view( string $view, array $vars = array(), boolean $return = FALSE )

Load View

This function is used to load a "view" file. It has three parameters:

    The name of the "view" file to be included.
    An associative array of data to be extracted for use in the view.
    TRUE/FALSE - whether to return the data or load it. In

some cases it's advantageous to be able to return data so that a developer can process it in some way.
Parameters

$view
$vars
$return
```